# QVector construct with multiple object

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qvector

I want to QVector start with several QSoundEffects (pratically). I try below code but not work.

QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds(4,new QSoundEffect());

I also don't want to go to a long method like this

.h file

```
QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds;
```

.cpp

```
reelSounds.resize(4);
QSoundEffect *sound0= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound1= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound2= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound3= new QSoundEffect();
reelSounds[0] = sound0;
reelSounds[1] = sound1;
reelSounds[2] = sound2;
reelSounds[3] = sound3;
```

or

```
QSoundEffect *sound0= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound1= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound2= new QSoundEffect();
QSoundEffect *sound3= new QSoundEffect();

reelSounds.append(sound0);
reelSounds.append(sound1);
reelSounds.append(sound2);
reelSounds.append(sound3);
```

Even if I use it like this(below) in the header file, I get an error.

```
QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds(4);
```

Is there a practical style of writing that I can finish in one line?

Comment: Please show the errors associated with each piece of code as text verbatim.  Also note that `QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds(4,new QSoundEffect());` will initialize all 4 elements of `reelSounds` with the *same* value.

Comment: What about using a simple for loop?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize the vector at header level, in your header:

```
QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds{new QSoundEffect(), new QSoundEffect(), new QSoundEffect(), new QSoundEffect()};
```

Slightly more elegant, in your header:

```
QVector<QSoundEffect *> reelSounds{4};
```

in source file:

```
std::generate(reelSounds.begin(), reelSounds.end(), [](){ return new QSoundEffect(); });
```